# Prevent Direct Access To PHP File

Tags: php

Let's say I have two domains: *domainA.com* and *domainB.com*. On *domainB.com* im going to use an iframe to access a PHP file on *domainA.com*.

Is there a way I can set an `if/else` statement so that no user can access that PHP file by going to `domainA.com/file.php`? That file should only load from an iframe on *domainB.com*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple ways. One which comes to my mind is using $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. If it's not "domainB.com" then exit execution or do something else. If you have to modify many files edit VHOST and create prepend script which will handle it globally.

Comment: Well the thing is the iframe wont just be on domainB.com it will be on multiple sites i just used that as a example.

Comment: @user2002220 hey! You're changing the specification!

Comment: So, where ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] != domainA.com)...

Comment: or if( ! in_array( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], $predefinedList ) )

Answer (score 0):

Try this on top of the file.php to make sure that file.php loads ONLY as an iframe on another page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var isInIFrame = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? true : false;

if(!isInIframe){
 document.execCommand('Stop'); //or window.stop(); dunno if this works on IE
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your websites on Apache, you might block access to file.php via .htaccess or your vhost;

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html